# A string representing variable name, how to find its type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of variables that I have defined so far in my program (I got it via dir() command). The list contains strings that are the names of those variables.

I want to find the type of each one of them. The `type()` command returns `"str"`. Which is what they are (literally speaking), but I want what the variable type really is, before converting its name to a string.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what use do you have, other than debugging purposes, to retrieve the type of every variable in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these variables are local, you can use `locals()['name']` or `vars()['name']` to access them (see section "Some more explanation" about their difference)

For global variables, use `globals()['name']`

```
a = 'some string'
b = 123
c = 1.234
d = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(type(locals()['a']))
print(type(locals()['b']))
print(type(locals()['c']))
print(type(locals()['d']))
```

**Output**

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'list'>
```

---

**Some more explanation:**

- `globals()` *always* returns the dictionary of the *module* namespace
- `locals()` *always* returns *a* dictionary of the *current* namespace
- `vars()` returns *either a* dictionary of the current namespace (if called with no argument) or *the* dictionary of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
>>> b = 3
>>> for var in dir():
    print(var, type(vars()[var]))


__annotations__ <class 'dict'>
__builtins__ <class 'module'>
__doc__ <class 'NoneType'>
__loader__ <class 'type'>
__name__ <class 'str'>
__package__ <class 'NoneType'>
__spec__ <class 'NoneType'>
b <class 'int'>
var <class 'str'>
```